# Orcad to Kicad schematic

Tags: schematics, kicad, orcad

I am looking into a reference design which was probably done using Orcad. I am using KiCAD for my design.

In the reference design, there are schematic symbols like >> and <<. According to [this guide](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~jan/spice/PSpice_CaptureGuideOrCAD.pdf), they seem to be 'off-page connector'. The guide says

"Off-page connectors are used to connect signals to 
like-named off-page connectors and hierarchical ports on 
other schematic pages within the same schematic folder. "

So, what is the off-page connector (>> or <<) equivalent at KiCAD? Global label or hierarchical connector?

Answer (score 2):

Kicad *global connector* is valid for whole schema project (all sheets), *hierarchical port* provides connector on hierarchical sheet. It makes significant difference if your  hierarchical sheet is reused more times or you have own library of sheets. In this case you can connect hierarchical connector on project sheet where hierarchical sheet(s) is/are placed.
It's analogous to programming: *global variable* vs. *procedure with arguments*.
You should be able use proper connector when you understand topology of your Orcad scheme.

Comment: Thanks. Here are examples of the usage on >> and << on a multisheet schematic    


The [source](http://imgur.com/xtnbDqJ) is
used in a different [sheet](http://imgur.com/hgdgaR9)
and also in this [sheet](http://imgur.com/WlbPWEJ )

So, are they essentially hierarchical label in KiCAD?

Comment: No, I'd say it's typical *global connector*. It's just name of MCU pin which is valid everywhere. I'm using it this way too (to provide MCU pin names as global labels).